# Authenticate WebSerivce with Facebook/OpenID

Tags: facebook, web-services, authentication, security

#### Simplified background:

1. Website that allows users to upload and comment some content, let's say images (classic CRUD web application).
2. Three ways to sing in into the system: classic username/password form, Facebook Conntect, OpenID (Google).
3. Public API that allows to read data from the system and create content (authenticated users).
4. Mobile (iOS/Android) application that uses API.

#### Problem:

Just like the website, the mobile application should provide FBConnect/OpenID authentication. However, I have absolutley no idea how to authenticate such an user in the website's public API.

How to create a secure authentication mechanism for mobile application that uses FB/Google for its authentication and on the same time uses my API for authenticated users?